# Kohana/php Headers and client library minor version mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, kohana-3

I have come to a very strange error, and as the title says i get:

`mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50095 Library:50149`

After some googling i found out that it might be caused by wrong `mysql/php` version, well that might be right, but the thing is i am using php framework `kohana` and if try to run this very simple connect code without that framework:

```
$sql = mysql_connect("server", "root", "passowrd") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db", $sql);
```

It works just fine, so my guess is that this error is caused by php script somewhere, could it be possible? And if so, can i fix it without updating server, because it's not really possible since i'm using public rented host.

Also just in case here is the `class` which connects to `DB`: http://pastebin.com/VFtj0re6

P.S i have tried to remove all code from `public function connect()` function, and add my own connection code which seems to be working, but it did not help.

Comment: You should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: @Matt wow pdo actually did work, i guess all i need to do now is to read up on pdo and mysqli. If you want you can write answer and i will accept it

Comment: NBD, I don't really need the rep for something like this. Happy to point you in the right direction.